# TextView does not fit the screen

Tags: android, textview

I have an activity with a TextView. I would like to align it on the bottom of the screen, in the center and I would like that the TextView fits the screen's width.

This is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".ShowCard" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#33000000"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />
```

The result is not what I have expected to see. The TextView is not full-screen in the width, but leaves a small free space right and left (like padding/border, but I've not set padding/border!).

Do you know why? Suggestions?

Comment: please add xml code with root view

Comment: Is there padding or margin in the containing layout?  Show the full XML.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >    
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#33000000"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Excuse me, I'm a stupid guy!
I've not see that in the container XML code were included four padding rows:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

I've deleted these rows and now everything is working correctly!

Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="#33000000"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />
```

Use the 'fill_parent' attribute, it should fill the entire width of the screen.

Comment: @Ndupza The 'fill_parent' attribute is deprecated. It' suggested to use 'match_parent'.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

from the parent relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".ShowCard" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#33000000"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />
```

use this